# What does kill 0 do actually?

Tags: process, kill, process-groups

In the `man page`, it says:

```
kill [ -s signal | -p ] [ -a ] [ -- ] pid ...
 pid... Specify the list of processes that kill should signal.  Each pid can be one of five things:
          0      All processes in the current process group are signaled
```

And I tried like this in bash:

```
$ man kill &
[1] 15247
$
[1]+  Stopped                 man kill
$ kill 0
$ ps
15247 pts/41   00:00:00 man
```

Here `0` is used as `pid`. As I understood, `kill 0` will kill all processes in the current process, which includes `pid15247`. However, it didn't do anything in this example. Does anyone have ideas about how to use it?

Comment: It sends a `SIGTERM` to the process, which it has done. The `man` command has chosen to ignore it.

Comment: @jordanm, no. a job started by an interactive shell has a different process group than the shell. That's how the shell can put it in foreground and background. See `ps -j` to see the process groups.

Comment: This question is actually a copy of SuperUser question [What does kill 0 do actually?](https://superuser.com/questions/563972/what-does-kill-0-do-actually) (which was migrated from StackOverflow).  See also questions about `kill -0` (note the dash), which is a different topic, [at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012527/what-does-kill-0-pid-in-a-shell-script-do "What does \`kill -0 $pid\` in a shell script do?") and here [on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169898/what-does-kill-0-do "What does \`kill -0\` do?").

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Like it says, it sends the signal to all the members of the process group of the caller.

Process groups are used to implement job control in the shell (they can be used for other things, but interactive shell job control is the main reason for their existence).

You'll notice that when you type <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, all the processes of the current jobs are killed, not only the one that started them. Also, that doesn't kill the background jobs.

That is achieved with process groups. A job is a group of processes started by a shell which the shell can put in background or foreground (set as the foreground process group of the terminal or not), and kill as a whole.

You can find out about process group ids and session ids with `ps -j` (`j` for <kbd>J</kbd>ob control).

To kill the process group of PGID `$x`, you do:

```
kill -- "-$x"
```

`kill 0` kills the process group of the caller.

Note that if you do: `/bin/kill 0`, the shell will start a new job to execute that `kill` command, so `kill` will only kill itself.

`kill` is usually a shell builtin though, so `kill` will kill the process group of the shell.

However, when the shell is interactive, it is the process managing process groups, so typically there's no other process in the process group of the shell. All the processes started by the shell, are in other process groups:

```
$ sleep 1000 &
[1] 22746
$ ps -j
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
22735 22735 22735 pts/23   00:00:00 zsh
22746 22746 22735 pts/23   00:00:00 sleep
22749 22749 22735 pts/23   00:00:00 ps
```

Above, `sleep` and `ps` are in two different process groups, one in background, one in foreground and they are different from the process group of the shell.

You could do though:

```
(man kill & sleep 1; ps -j; kill 0)
```

The interactive shell would start a new process group for that subshell, and both the subshell and man (and the other commands started by man like your pager, groff...) would be in the same process group, so `kill 0` would work there. (the `sleep` above is to give enough time for the pager to start so we can see it in the `ps -j` output before we kill it).

Comment: `kill -- -$x` actually says `bash: kill: (-63531) - No such process` in bash 5.0.11(1)-release on MacOS 10.14 but it is sure process exists and running. `pkill -P` works fine

Comment: @kyb $x must be a process group id not process id. See the output of `ps -j` to find out about pgids