# Using telnet command without protocol negotiation

Tags: telnet, serial-console, protocols

I'm using telnet to connect to a serial port via a TCP/IP server. I need a raw, unfiltered, unbuffered connection, and can get most of the way there, but no matter what I do telnet sends protocol negotiation commands when it connects.

This is strange, because "man telnet" page says:

```
When connecting to ports other than the telnet port, telnet does not attempt telnet
protocol negotiations. This makes it possible to connect to services that do not
support the telnet protocol without making a mess.
```

But, although I'm connecting to a non-standard port, telnet negotiates:

```
linuxdev:~ griscom$ telnet 172.16.250.49 2023
Trying 172.16.250.49...
Negotiating binary mode with remote host.
Connected to 172.16.250.49.
                           Escape character is '^]'.
```

And, as the man page warns, this makes a mess.

Is there a way to use telnet as a completely transparent TCP/IP client? Or, is there some other tool I could use?

Details:

- Running telnet on an Ubuntu 22.04 system
- Server is a [USR-TCP232-T2 ethernet to serial converter](https://www.pusr.com/products/serial-to-ethernet-converter-modules-usr-tcp232-t2.html)
- Serial port is connected to a Linux system's console, so I need unbuffered transparency so I can, e.g. run `vim` or type control characters

Edit: I figured out the problem. `telnet` by default runs in "line" mode, collecting characters and sending them the next time a CR is typed. I need it to run in "character" mode, where it sends data as-is.

Problem: I can't set "character" mode without `telnet` negotiating that change with the other end of the line. Proof: if I connect to the serial adapter with an unconfigured telnet, I'll get no negotiation characters sent to the adaptor. But, if I use `^]` to drop into command mode, and then type `mode character`, `telnet` will immediately negotiate with the other end, making a mess. (The same thing happens if I use a `.telnetrc` file to configure the connection to character mode.)

So, there's no way for `telnet` to connect to a port in "character" model without sending spurious command bytes to that port. I'll need a different solution.

Comment: To me, it seems that the device will start negotiation, and probably it set to the right values. You should try to find if the negotiation is ok, and ev. configure the converter

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I'll check this with Wireshark and see exactly what's transpiring between `telnet` and the USR-TCP232-T2; will report back.

Comment: You can get debug output from the telnet client by creating a file
`~/.telnetrc` with remote hostname on 1st line, and ` set options` indented
by 1 space on 2nd line. eg `printf '172.16.250.49\n set options\n' >~/.telnetrc`

Comment: I figured it out: see the edit to my question. I'll likely post a new answer based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/311680/88234 , which I've used many times in the past although not over the network.

Comment: Did you check what you can configure in your converter? I think the first step is to optimize configuration then you may find a way not to negotiate. And if it negotiate, it means that the client know what is it doing. Note: for sure you can configure: serial ports requires a lot of configuration (baud, start/stop bit, parity, etc.). Often it is in a different TCP port (e.g. one less the normal communication port).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The converter isn't the problem, except that it can't be configured to negotiate Telnet protocol. The problem is Telnet; it insists on sending negotiation characters when put into binary mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `netcat` (`nc`) for a transparent connection

```
   nc {host} {port}
```

Although the `telnet` client is correctly not attempting negotiation, it will always respond to a negotiation request by the server. I believe that may be what's happening in this instance. You can avoid any and all negotiation by using `nc`.

Note that you may find `nc` appears to be in line mode. It isn't, it's just that the terminal driver hasn't been asked to go into raw mode:

```
stty raw; nc {host} {port}
```

Once you do this you will not be able to use the terminal session to quit `nc`; you will need to send it a signal from elsewhere:

```
ps | grep -w nc    # 60883 pty0     00:00:00 nc
kill 60883         # ^this^
```

Comment: I do not think it is a fault of telnet package. From what I get of the message, it is the device which starts negotiation (else: why getting binary mode?)

Comment: Unfortunately, `nc` still cooks the output, doing I/O line by line with local echo, which plays hell with (e.g.) running `vim`. It also interprets control characters locally (e.g. `^C`, `^D`).

Comment: @DanielGriscom it's not `nc` that's processing the characters in line mode. See: `stty raw; nc {host} {port}`, but don't expect to be able to exit from it - you'll need to send it a signal from elsewhere. I've updated my answer